# Let atom editor recognize external APIs

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to set up a python like environment with Atom-editor on a Linux machine.

I find the `autocomplete-python` package that uses `jedi`.

In the settings of the package I tried to add some python path where the APIs are (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`) but then the autocompletion doesn't recognize these libraries (for example the PyQt ones)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody having the same issue please look [here](https://github.com/sadovnychyi/autocomplete-python/issues/132).

Basically everything should work out of the box, but if it does not -- try to configure path to python executable with which you have installed your external module. If it's still fails to complete -- try to configure extra path to python modules. (usually your site-packages directory)